# How to set frequency of fm radio programatically from android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I am using this intent to start fm radio

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.fm");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

In samsung note2 I can open fm radio through this intent. So my question is how can I set frequency programmatically like `i.putExtra("setFreq", 94.3);`. Is there any parameter I have to pass through the intent. I don't know it is possible or not. Please help.thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [this forum-post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=45066788&postcount=3) to find a list of intents to control the fm radio:

- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.on
- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.off
- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.prev
- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.next
- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.fav0
- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.fav1

[upto..]

- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.fav11
- com.sec.android.app.fm.widget.frequency

I don't know how to use the frequency intent, but i've tried successfully the others on my Galaxy S3 (with the Llama app).